# Transit visa Dubai while travelling with flydubai

Tags: transit, airports, transit-visas, dxb

I am travelling from Entebbe (departure 22:15) to Faisalabad (arrival 03:20) with flydubai. I have a transit of more than 18 hours. What facilities I can get from flydubai during transit? Hotel? Meal? Dubai connect? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

None that are free.

As per their [conditions of carriage](https://www.flydubai.com/en/information/policies/conditions-of-carriage) you are entitled in case of delays:

> (b) Unless applicable laws provide otherwise, if your flight is
>   cancelled or delayed for reasons other than outlined in Articles 9.1
>   and 9.2(a) above the following will apply to you:
>
> (i) if the departure of your flight is delayed less than three hours
>   no compensation or refund will be given;
>
> (ii) if the departure of your flight is delayed more than three hours
>   you will receive a refreshment voucher, applicable to the time of day;
>   and
>
> (iii) if your flight is cancelled you may be re-booked on the next
>   available flight to the same destination free of charge. You can also
>   change the date of your return journey free of charge, subject to
>   availability. Alternatively, you can cancel your reservation and
>   receive a full refund in the form of a Voucher, unless applicable laws
>   provide otherwise.
>
> (c) The three remedies in Articles 9.2(b)(i) to 9.2(b)(iii) do not
>   affect any rights you may have under Article 15.6. Those remedies and
>   rights represent the sole and exclusive remedies and rights available
>   to you if your carriage is affected by one of the events listed in
>   Article 9.2(b).

Or in case of denied boarding:

> (a) If you are denied boarding on a flight for which you have a valid
>   Booking Confirmation you will be entitled to travel on the next
>   available flight, receive refreshments and care appropriate to the
>   time of day and duration until the next available flight. You will
>   also receive a refund of the total fare for that sector in the form of
>   a Voucher. You may also change the date of your return journey free of
>   charge once, subject to availability. This does not apply if we refuse
>   to carry you for reasons permitted by these Conditions of Carriage
>   (see, for example, Articles 6 and 7).
>
> (b) If Article 9.3(a) applies to you, we will pay to you any
>   compensation due to you under applicable laws.
>
> (c) Apart from your rights under this Article 9.3, we will have no
>   liability to you for any loss or expense whatsoever.

I suggest you [apply for a transit visa](https://www.flydubai.com/en/plan/visas-and-passports/uae-visas) (this is not a free service) and then manage your time in Dubai.